# Magento input values in editable grid are lost on changing page display limit count

Tags: magento, grid

I am making a editable grid in magento. Now when I use pages to change displayed values in page- 20,50,100,200, It sends an ajax request and fetch data and still saves the already checked boxes(earlier checked boxes are still selected), but all of my input values in grid are lost. how can I save those values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually these values are stored in javascript(grid.js) global object.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in the Grid `setSaveParametersInSession()`

Comment: thanks. Could you Tell me how can I save override this function to save my input parameters